# In the time between an edit and its subsequent acceptance/rejection, there isn't a way to look at the original post

Tags: support, suggested-edits

There are times that I've made an edit and then second guessed something and wanted to look at the original post.  Unfortunately, while one is awaiting approval for said edit, it's no longer possible to look at the edit history. Anyone else think it would be a good idea to change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps :

- Go to your profile.

> [image]

- Click on Activity Tab

> [image]

- Click on suggestions within the tab

> [image]

- Finally, click on the relevant suggested edit.

> [image: Freehand Circles!]

You will be able to see the edit and the original.

<strike>I don't think you will be able to make any further changes, though.</strike>
As pointed out by ShaWizDowArd, one can make edits to suggested edit within the five minutes grace period, assuming of course the edit wasn't yet approved or rejected. All of those are merged to one single edit.

Comment: One can make edits to suggested edit within the five minutes grace period, assuming of course the edit wasn't yet approved or rejected. All of those are merged to one single edit. [Proof](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15042).

Comment: This misses the point of the feature request. Even though the information is there, newcomers aren't likely to seek it out. A notification reminds them to check, and gives them an easy-access link to do so.

Comment: @Knight I don't think so. He asked only if it's possible or not, and it is possible.